Langchain Javascript: Talk to your CSV file using Open AI
I have simple requirement, which I am not able to do. I have CSV of 3000 lines and around 15 column . I want to store it in Faiss Vector Store DB and want to query different question.
I can see that, CSV file is getting loaded correctly in Faiss database as file.
But still It is giving very random answer or some times, It is telling that, data do not exists.
Basically CSV consist following main fields
sold order number, cust_first_name, cust_last_name, sold_order_status, model, model_desc. 

Below is the code, I have written, but Its not working. I am not sure, what mistake I am doing.
import dotenv from "dotenv";
import { FaissStore } from "@langchain/community/vectorstores/faiss";
import { RetrievalQAChain, loadQAStuffChain } from "langchain/chains";
import {
  ChatPromptTemplate,
  HumanMessagePromptTemplate,
  SystemMessagePromptTemplate,
} from "@langchain/core/prompts";
import { CSVLoader } from "langchain/document_loaders/fs/csv";
import { OpenAI, OpenAIEmbeddings } from "@langchain/openai";

// Initialize dotenv to load environment variables
dotenv.config();

class NSOLoggerCSV {

  private model: OpenAI;
  private MODEL_NAME = "gpt-3.5-turbo";
  private EMBEDDING_MODEL_NAME = 'text-embedding-3-large'
  
  private DB_PATH = "./vector-store-csv-nso";
  private FILE_TO_BE_LOADED =
    "./v_so_active_202407101002.csv";

  constructor() {
    // Create a new instance of the OpenAI model
    this.model = new OpenAI({
      temperature: 0,
      model: this.MODEL_NAME,
      streaming: true,
      callbacks: [
        {
          handleLLMNewToken(token) {
            process.stdout.write(token);
          },
        },
      ],
    });
  }

  /**
   * This is used to load the csv file into Faiss Vector store, which will later used
   * to query.
   */
  async processCSVToVectorStore() {
    console.log(`Stared Loading the  Vector Store from ${this.FILE_TO_BE_LOADED}`);

    const csvLoader = new CSVLoader(this.FILE_TO_BE_LOADED);
    const documents = await csvLoader.load();

    console.log("Total Length Of Documents ", documents.length);

    const embeddings = new OpenAIEmbeddings({
      model: this.EMBEDDING_MODEL_NAME, 
    });
    let vectorStore : FaissStore = await FaissStore.fromDocuments(documents, embeddings);
    await vectorStore.save(this.DB_PATH);
    console.log("Faiss Vector Store Created Successfully!");
  }

  /**
   * 
   * @param question Question asked by end user to CSV file
   * @returns 
   */
  async useFaissVectorStrore(question: string) {
    const embeddings = new OpenAIEmbeddings({
      model: this.EMBEDDING_MODEL_NAME,
    });
    const vectorStore = await FaissStore.load(this.DB_PATH, embeddings);
  

    const system_template = `Your Name is John. Your job is to analyse the csv provided to you and answer based on csv.
If you don't know the answer, just say that you don't know, don't try to make up an answer.
----------------
{context}`;
    const messages = [
      SystemMessagePromptTemplate.fromTemplate(system_template),
      HumanMessagePromptTemplate.fromTemplate("{question}"),
    ];
    const CHAT_PROMPT = ChatPromptTemplate.fromMessages(messages);

    const chain = new RetrievalQAChain({
      combineDocumentsChain: loadQAStuffChain(this.model, {
        prompt: CHAT_PROMPT,
      }),
      retriever: vectorStore.asRetriever({k:4}),
      returnSourceDocuments: true,
      verbose: false,
    });

    const resAsStream = await chain.stream({
      query: question,
    });

    return resAsStream;
  }
}

export default NSOLoggerCSV;



On further investigation, I found that, Vector Store DB, which is Faiss in my case, is not returning relevant document and hence, LLM is not able to answer properly.
Can any one please help, why Vector store is not returning relevant documents?
